# App launcher icon and background state icon are different - Flutter App

Tags: flutter, appicon, launcher-icon

**EDIT:** I have deleted all the icons generated by the library and tried @Liam's suggestion, ending up with a proper launcher app icon but **NO** background state icon at all. Photo attached.

[no background state app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iYMO.jpg)

**Original Post**

Lately I have changed my flutter app launcher icon using [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) package, and everything seems to work just fine, just one problem:

The launcher icon and the backgrounded state icon on **iOS devices** are different.

Also worth mentioning the fact that the background state icon is an icon that I have perviously used for the launcher app icon, but changed it to the current one, and deleted the relevant image from the project.

**The implementation:**

I haven't used any config file, just added the proper dependency and  wrote the following lines in pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/logo3.jpeg
```

Finishing with running the following command in terminal:

```
$ flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

I have tried flutter clean and rebuild, tried to re-install the app, and also changing the icon and re-running

```
$ flutter pub get

$ flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

I have looked all over the web, and it seems no one experience that kind of issue, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Photos to get the idea:

[launcher app icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM7tk.jpg)

[background state icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsP4B.jpg)

Comment: Please share your `flutter_launcher_icons.yaml` or `flutter_icons:` in `pubspec.yaml` depending on your choice of config, currently its hard to tell anything

Comment: Post edited @jan

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting your device, it deletes OS cache

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had the same problem. Here is how I fixed the app icon on ios:

1. go to the website `appicon.co`
2. drag your logo into the box
   [image]
3. select all the platforms where you want to change the icon
   [image]
4. scroll down and click on "Generate"
5. open explorer and go to downloads
6. unzip the generated file
7. open explorer again
8. go to `your project` > `ios` > `Runner` > `Assets.xcassets`
9. remove the directory: `AppIcon.appiconset`
10. on the other explorer tab go to `the unzipped directory` > `Assets.xcassets` > `AppIcon.appiconset` > `_`
11. drag and drop anything inside back to: `AppIcon.appiconset`
12. go back into the `Assets.xcassets` directory
13. drag and drop the directory: `AppIcon.appiconset` to the other explorer tab where you already are inside `your project` > `ios` > `Runner` > `Assets.xcassets`

---

If you don't understand something just write a comment

---

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately it didn't work. I have followed your exact steps.

Comment: pity that it doesn't work. I have an idea how you can get more answers: 1. work for points on stack overflow: as min 50. 2. set a bounty -- 3 days after you asked the question you can set a bounty

Comment: I will check on that. That said, something weird happened, I have deleted all the icons generated by the library mentioned in the post, and used your suggestion again, ending up with an app icon working fine, and *NO* app icon in the background state at all. any suggestions?

Comment: I am sorry but i don't know how to solve the problem. I think the bounty way is the best: so i upvote your question that you have 10 points more. That's anything I can do right now